# Memory issue when wrapping C++ code with Python

Tags: python, c++, cython

I am trying to integrate some native C++ code into a Python library, I've implemented the functionality and I'm using Cython to bind it in Python.

The method I'm trying to expose is the following :

```
double* doStuff(double *f, int size, double lambda) {
    std::vector<double> f_vector(f, f + size);
    auto result = doStuffWithVectors(f_vector, lambda);

    return &result[0];
}
```

To bind the code to Cython, I have a pxd file with the following :

```
cdef extern from "mylib.h":
    double* doStuff(double *signal, int size, double l)
```

And the following pyx :

```
from cython.view cimport array as cvarray
import numpy as np

cimport cmylib

cpdef double[:] doStuff(double[::1] signal, double l):
    return <double[:len(signal)]> cl1potts.doStuff(&signal[0], len(signal), l)
```

The code works great **most of the time**. Sometimes, the returned array is filled with NaNs / Infinite values.

I can't find any rhyme or reason to when the results are invalid, sometimes the same inputs will return a valid result, sometimes it won't.

I modified the C++ code to save the result to a file right before returning it, and I have the expected values, something is wrong when doing the transfer between C++ and Python.

My suspicion is that creating the python object sometimes takes too long, and the C++ program exits before the operation is done, therefore creating an undefined behaviour.

Is something like that a possibility ? And if so how can I change my code to avoid it. Do I need to create an array with **new** ? But wouldn't that cause memory leaks ?

Comment: What are the type and lifetime of `result`? We can't tell without seeing `doStuffWithVectors`, but I strongly suspect you're returning a dangling pointer to a deallocated array and everything is Undefined Behaviour shortly after

Comment: `auto result = doStuffWithVectors(f_vector, lambda); return &result[0];` -- The `result` is a local variable.  When `doStuff` returns, that local variable goes out-of-scope into a puff of smoke.  So what will happen to that buffer that belonged to `result`?  It's gone.

Comment: *I can't find any rhyme or reason to when the results are invalid* -- I have to ask -- are you a python programmer, and not a C++ programmer?  A C++ programmer would see right away what the issue is.  As to why it works some times, you can chalk that up to "undefined behavior", something that doesn't exist in most other computer languages, where you are protected from things like this.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie *When `doStuff` returns, that local variable goes out-of-scope into a puff of smoke.* you can’t tell for sure without knowing what exactly `doStuffWithVectors` returns. Does it return a reference to a [static local variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables)? We can’t tell without seeing it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am indeed primarly a Python programmer, I know the syntax of C++ and the basics, but not much more beyond that.

I did find a way to fix the issue though, by passing a result array and filling it instead of returning